# Dynamic Require with Webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm using React, Node, Express, and Webpack and I'm basically trying to do dynamic requires relative to my filesystem. I want to automatically call my route pages from my /routes/ directory without having to explicitly call each of them. Please let me know the best way of going about this. (fyi: each route has its own individual imports which means I need webpack to still transpile jsx)

Comment: How do you mean? Something like `const { page1, page2 ... } from '/routes'`?